# Can I substitute "if they are" for "should they be"? The differences between the two?

Tags: subjunctives

> For migrating checkerspots, there's an additional problem: Los Angeles lies directly in their path **should they be** inclined to try migrating to cooler climates. (From ACT test)

Can I substitute the bold part with "if they are"? It sounds the same to me.

Since "should they be" and "if they be" are worded in different ways, are there any nuances between the two?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the word *'If'* (expressing condition) is omitted, the auxiliary verb precedes the subject :

> If I were a king ...
> = Were I a king ...

> If I had been a bird ...
> =  Had I been a bird ...

In case of simple present tense in the if-clause, the auxiliary verb *'Should'* precedes the subject :

> If they are ... = Should they be ...

> If they should be selected ...
> = Should they be selected

These are **subjunctive with inversion**.